# How to get the result of the qr code to the dialog box then will open to the another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I have an app that will scan Qr code. The Qr code have a default value that if you scan it will go to a dialog box with the result and will call the activity with the same result

I want to happen is when the result of the qr scan is in the dialog box if the result of it is the same with the activity it will open the activity if not it will call a wrong qr.

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            //We will get scan results here
            IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            //check for null
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.getContents() == null) {

                    // Toast.makeText(this, "Scan Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    //show dialogue with result
                    showResultDialogue(result.getContents());
                }
            } else {
                // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

        //method to construct dialogue with scan results
        public void showResultDialogue(final String result) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
            } else {
                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            }
            builder.setTitle("Scan Result")
                    .setMessage(result)
                    .setPositiveButton("View your Location", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // continue with delete
                            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Scan Result", result);
                            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);


                            Intent nxt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Acad1.class);
                            startActivity(nxt);


                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried and where do you have problems in your current implementation? Please share the relevant parts if your code,

Comment: the code is in post

Comment: What happens when you run your app? What do you want it to do differently?

Answer (score 0):

No. What i want is when you scan a qr code with the same name with activity it will open first the dialog box and then when you click the view location it will go to the activity with the same name of the result.